# Node.js unexpected stack overflow with multiple get requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-overflow

I have a function that GETs a JSON object from a remote server, or from a local cache on-disk.

In a use-case, i have to call this function several thousand times with varying arguments, but when i do so, i get max stack overflow errors. I must be making a recursive call somewhere, but i can't see where it could be as my process.nextTick function calls seem to be in the right place.

I get none of my log.error readouts in the console, which would be evident if any of the recursive calls to retry the request were made.

The console output shows a repeated occurrence of

> (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

then...

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Then the program exits.

Can anyone offer any help regarding what i may be doing wrong? I'm completely stumped.

Below is the function that invokes the problematic function "tf2inv.loadInventory()"

```
function refreshInventories(accounts, force, callback) {    
    //job executes download function, then pushes to inventories object
    var inventories = {};
    var Qinv = async.queue(function (task, invCallback) {
        tf2inv.loadInventory(
            task.force,
            task.steamid,
            function(inv, alias) {
                inventories[alias] = inv;
                process.nextTick(invCallback);
            }
        );
    }, 100)

    //when all queue jobs have finished, callback with populated inventories object
    Qinv.drain = function (err) {
        log.info('All inventories downloaded');
        callback(inventories);
    }

    //adding jobs to the queue
    for (var i = accounts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Qinv.push({
            force: force,
            steamid: accounts[i]
        });
    };
}
```

Shown here is the function that either parses from the cache, or requests from the remote server.

```
//tf2inv
var loadInventory = function(force, sid, callback) {
    var invLoc = invFolder+sid
    if(force) { 
        if(fs.existsSync(invLoc)) {
            fs.unlinkSync(invLoc);
        }
    }

    if(fs.existsSync(invLoc)) {
        var body = fs.readFileSync(invLoc);
        try {
            var inventory = JSON.parse(body);
        } catch (e) {
            fs.unlinkSync(invLoc);
            log.error("parsing " + sid+"'s inventory");
            loadInventory(true, sid, invFolder, callback);  
            return;
        }
        process.nextTick(function() { callback(inventory, sid) })
        return;
    } else {
        var urlPre = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=";
        var urlSidPre = "&steamid=";
        var urlInvSuf = "&inventory=yes";
        var URL = urlPre+steam_API+urlSidPre+sid+urlInvSuf;
        http.get(URL, function (res) {
            var body = '';
            res.on('data', function (data) {
                body+=data; 
                fs.appendFile(invLoc, data);
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                try {
                    inventory = JSON.parse(body);
                } catch (e) {
                    if(fs.existsSync(invLoc)) {
                        fs.unlinkSync(invLoc);
                    }
                    log.error("parsing " + sid+"'s downloaded inventory");
                    loadInventory(force, sid, invFolder, callback)
                    return;
                }
                process.nextTick(function() { callback(inventory, sid) })
                return;
            });
            res.on('error', function (e, socket) {
                log.error(sid + " inventory error")
                if(fs.existsSync(invLoc)) {
                    fs.unlinkSync(invLoc);
                }
                log.debug('Retrying inventory') 
                loadInventory(force, sid, invFolder, callback);
                return;
            })
            res.on('close', function () {res.emit('end'); log.error('connection closed')})
        })
        .on('error', function(e) {
            log.error(JSON.stringify(e));
            if(fs.existsSync(invLoc)) {
                fs.unlinkSync(invLoc);
            }
            log.debug('Retrying inventory') 
            loadInventory(force, sid, invFolder, callback)
            return;
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: In that catch handler, the `loadInventory(true, sid, invFolder, callback);` looks like it could be infinitely recursing.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Bergi, thanks for helping. The recursive call won't be the issue as the log.error console output prior to that call is never seen

Comment: Also, the stack trace isn't shown as it's a stack overflow error. The console output from this section of my program is detailed in my post. Austin

Comment: Then you'd have to use your debugger and halt on the error, where you can insect the current stack.

Comment: Is there a native way of doing this? I can't find any resource on handling max stack overflow errors

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be failing to parse the body coming back from the server. It then immediately calls itself again, failing again, infinitely looping and causing a stack overflow.

I suggest you do not retry automatically on a failed parse - if it fails once, it is likely to fail again. It would be best to call back with the error, and let the part of your programming calling this handle the error, or passing it back to the point where it can let the user know that something is wrong.

Comment: Depending on what your logger is, it could be outputting the error asynchronously, which means that you won't see it if the process has crashed before it can be output.

Comment: The logger is just a proxy to console.log which has colour coded log subtypes. In this case. It's synchronous, and I would see the console log the error. I don't see this, which makes me think that the problem is not with the recursive function call. When I'm home, I'll remove the error handling and confirm that this is the case.